# How can i change uiimage color in iphone sdk xcode

Tags: iphone

I am using different images and i want to include change color option. But i cant. Any body help me?

Comment: Do you want to "tint" the images with a color? What do you mean with "change color option"?

Comment: if the whole image is white. if i select black button , then the whole image will be black...etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to do image tinting, see UIImage+Tint.m in [kballard/MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/kballard/MGImageUtilities). If you want wholesale color replacement (e.g. treat an image as a silhouette and change the entire color to one flat color), see UIImage+Tint.m in [mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities).

Comment: Kevin@Thanks allot, Its working now. I can easily change the color of any image.

Comment: Getting memory warning while using some very resolution images. Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Its latest and most simple way to do it.

```
           theImageView.image = [theImageView.image     imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
           [theImageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Also, it's possible to mark image as template right in the image assets entry. Then set tintColor for containing imageView.

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this is to desaturate your image, and add a tint on top of that image with the color you desire.

**Desaturate**

```
-(UIImage *) getImageWithUnsaturatedPixelsOfImage:(UIImage *)image {
    const int RED = 1, GREEN = 2, BLUE = 3;

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width*2, image.size.height*2);

    int width = imageRect.size.width, height = imageRect.size.height;

    uint32_t * pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(uint32_t));
    memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [image CGImage]);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            uint8_t * rgbaPixel = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y*width+x];
            uint32_t gray = (0.3*rgbaPixel[RED]+0.59*rgbaPixel[GREEN]+0.11*rgbaPixel[BLUE]);

            rgbaPixel[RED] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[GREEN] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[BLUE] = gray;
        }
    }

    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(pixels);

    UIImage * resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:2 orientation:0];
    CGImageRelease(newImage);

    return resultUIImage;
}
```

**Overlay With Color**

```
-(UIImage *) getImageWithTintedColor:(UIImage *)image withTint:(UIColor *)color withIntensity:(float)alpha {
    CGSize size = image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, FALSE, 2);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, alpha);

    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(CGPointZero.x, CGPointZero.y, image.size.width, image.size.height));

    UIImage * tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tintedImage;
}
```

**How-To**

```
//For a UIImageView
yourImageView.image = [self getImageWithUnsaturatedPixelsOfImage:yourImageView.image];
yourImageView.image = [atom getImageWithTintedColor:yourImageView.image withTint:[UIColor redColor] withIntensity:0.7];

//For a UIImage
yourImage = [self getImageWithUnsaturatedPixelsOfImage:yourImage];
yourImage = [atom getImageWithTintedColor:yourImageView.image withTint:[UIColor redColor] withIntensity:0.7];
```

*You can change the color of the tint to whatever you desire.*

Comment: here image display in gray color but if i want to display color with different color then what to do??

Comment: If you've implemented my solution all you have to do is this 

`yourImage = [atom getImageWithTintedColor:yourImageView.image withTint:[UIColor redColor] withIntensity:0.7];`

Comment: I'm getting errors with this: <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0