# Change the color of UIIMAGE +UIKIT+iphone

Tags: iphone, uicolor

I want to change the color of the UIIMAGE on button click event.

Example:-
I had UIIMAGE of white color or grey color
Where if i click the yellow(button) then the shape color changes to yellow.
IF i click the red color then color change to red.
If i click on black then color change to black.

Image like this:- [image]
I had refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690814/how-can-i-change-uiimage-color-in-iphone-sdk-xcode) link.And get the code from github.It is working properly.

But the problem is when i changes the color from white to red.It is done properly.
But then red to yellow.Then it is showing me pinking color(Mixture of yellow and red).

Please any one help me.
How can i change the color of uiimage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: means you want to change it`s gray-scale of image....

Comment: i want to change the color of image.

Comment: did u means u want effect like change colorfull image in b/w then... ucan add any gradiant shade in image...try this one...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298867/convert-image-to-grayscale

Comment: @Thanx for the reply Aj_ But want to do like :-change the color of Triangle image(Red colored image) into yellow trianglecolored image..

Answer (score 2):

Change the image color to something lighter like white.
It will append new color properly.